# Certificate Validation is being used while making a POST call using httpclient even though I pass a bearer token for auth

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, postman, httpclient

I get the following error when I try to make a `POST request` using `HttpClient` in C# -

> "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
> relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> {"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
> procedure."}"

And this is the chunk of code I use -

```
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            try
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
                return await httpClient.PostAsync(apiurl, content);
            }
```

Based on the error, it seems like it is trying to validate certificates somehow, however if I am using a bearer token for authentication, should it not really validate the certificates?

Also, the same request passes in `POSTMAN` (with SSL verification off) but I see the following warning -

> "Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames"

(I am confused again what certificates it is trying to use espeically seeing SSL verification is unabled for my POSTMAN)

I also added the following code to see what happens when I print out sender, cert, chain or errors but they are all null (so I cannot debug any info as to what certificates the call is trying to validate).

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain,
    errors) =>
```

Is there any insight on what I can do about this?

Comment: _"even though I pass a bearer token for auth"_ makes it sound like you think that passing a bearer token should stop the client validating the server's SSL certificate.

Comment: SSL and authentication don't have anything to do with each other. Your server cert is invalid (as postman says) thus the client rejects it ... ie, the certificate is issued for a different domain. The best way to solve such an issue is providing a correct certificate at your server (or use the correct hostname to access your server)

Comment: The way HTTPS works is that *first* a TLS connection is established, and *then* the HTTP protocol is run on top of this TLS connection. If the TLS connection fails you get nothing.

Comment: Ahh i see! That makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much for the explanation everyone!!